# mysql query where and group by

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, where-clause

I have a database table and in the status field it contains paid, pending, draft, expired and successful. how can i groupy by date and all status and expired status.

i have query like this

```
SELECT count(*) as total,
    date_format(insert_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as `a`,  status
FROM transaction
WHERE insert_date BETWEEN '2022-11-24 00:00:00' AND '2022-12-08 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(insert_date, '%d'), status
```

[image]

how to group all status and expired status in 1 date?
for example in date 04-12-2022 must be total = 19 status all and total = 8 status expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `Total` and `Expired` in separate columns of the same row.

```
SELECT date_format(insert_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS Date,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(status = 'EXPIRED') AS expired
FROM transaction
WHERE insert_date BETWEEN '2022-11-24 00:00:00' AND '2022-12-08 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a
```